# Erro com o retorno de uma função para pegar século de um ano

Tags: javascript

Em uma uma função em JS onde o usuário passa o ano como parâmetro e a função retorna qual o século desse ano, porém minha função sempre retorna 1.

```
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    if (year => 1 || year <= 101)return 1
    else if (year => 102 || year <= 201)return 2
    else if (year => 202 || year <= 301) return 3

    else if (year => 302 || year <= 401)return 4
    else if (year => 402 || year <= 501)return 5
    else if (year => 502 || year <= 601)return 6
    else if (year => 602 || year <= 701)return 7

    else if (year => 702 || year <= 801)return 8
    else if (year => 802 || year <= 901)return 9

    else if (year => 902 || year <= 1001)return 10
    else if (year => 1002 || year <= 1101)return 11
    else if (year => 1102 || year <= 1201)return 12

    else if (year => 1202 || year <= 1301)return 13
    else if (year => 1302 || year <= 1401)return 14
    else if (year => 1402 || year <= 1501)return 15
    else if (year => 1502 || year <= 1601)return 16
    else if (year => 1602 || year <= 1701)return 17
    else if (year => 1702 || year <= 1801)return 18
    else if (year => 1802 || year <= 1901)return 19
    else if (year => 1902 || year <= 2001)return 20
    else if (year => 2002 || year <= 2101)return 21

}
```

Comment: seu código está bem confuso, sugiro que refatore e se baseie nessa função do link a seguir: https://gist.github.com/dillansimmons/6e4b0cf88b99cc3a9149eebd1ded349a

Comment: Cara a comparação está errada, não é **=>** para maior ou igual isto é uma **arrow function** e tem outra funcionalidade. O sinal de maior ou igual é este **>=** em Javascript.

Comment: Além disso, você tem que substituir `||` pelo `&&`. Porém o correto é refatorar o código. Dá para encontrar o resultado com uma divisão

Comment: Antes de mais nada, é erro básico de sintaxe no `=>`, como já dito pelo colega @LeAndrade. Isto aqui não é um símbolo de comparação: `=>`, isto é: `>=` - Mesmo assim, qualquer valor atenderá a condição `(year >= 1 || year <= 101)`. "Maior que um **OU** menor que 101". Se quer restringir a uma faixa, teria que dizer `(year >= 1 && year <= 101)` "Maior que um **E** menor que 101". Ambas verdadeiras.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pura matemática pode ser bem mais simples.

Na verdade poderia ser mais simples ainda. EU tenho quase certeza que seu algoritmo original está errado e por isso para reproduzir os mesmos resultados tiver que fazer alguns `if`s que deveria ser desnecessários e uma subtração que também não parece correta, mas fiz para dar o mesmo resultado. Se desejar que eu faça o jeito certo é só falar.

```js
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    if (year == 1) return 1;
    if (year > 2101 || year < 1) return null;
    return Math.trunc((year - 2) / 100) + 1;
}
console.log(centuryFromYear(-1));
console.log(centuryFromYear(0));
console.log(centuryFromYear(1));
console.log(centuryFromYear(50));
console.log(centuryFromYear(100));
console.log(centuryFromYear(101));
console.log(centuryFromYear(102));
console.log(centuryFromYear(150));
console.log(centuryFromYear(2000));
console.log(centuryFromYear(2100));
console.log(centuryFromYear(2200));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Math/Century.js).

Answer (score 2):

Na sua condição você está colocando `||` ao invés de `&&`. Pense bem, se o usuário "enviar" qualquer ano acima de 1 ele sempre irá cair no primeiro `IF` pois a primeira condição vai satisfazer a função.

> `if (year >= 1 || year <= 101)return 1`

Lembre-se que o operador lógico **OU** necessita apenas que **uma** das condições seja verdadeira para entrar no `IF`.

Neste caso, você precisa apenas trocar o seu operador `||` por `&&`, onde será verificado se o ano informado está **entre** o período que deseja.

```
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    if (year >= 1 && year <= 101)return 1
    else if (year >= 102 && year <= 201)return 2
    else if (year >= 202 && year <= 301) return 3

    else if (year >= 302 && year <= 401)return 4
    else if (year >= 402 && year <= 501)return 5
    else if (year >= 502 && year <= 601)return 6
    else if (year >= 602 && year <= 701)return 7

    else if (year >= 702 && year <= 801)return 8
    else if (year >= 802 && year <= 901)return 9

    else if (year >= 902 && year <= 1001)return 10
    else if (year >= 1002 && year <= 1101)return 11
    else if (year >= 1102 && year <= 1201)return 12

    else if (year >= 1202 && year <= 1301)return 13
    else if (year >= 1302 && year <= 1401)return 14
    else if (year >= 1402 && year <= 1501)return 15
    else if (year >= 1502 && year <= 1601)return 16
    else if (year >= 1602 && year <= 1701)return 17
    else if (year >= 1702 && year <= 1801)return 18
    else if (year >= 1802 && year <= 1901)return 19
    else if (year >= 1902 && year <= 2001)return 20
    else if (year >= 2002 && year <= 2101)return 21
}
```

Links úteis:
[Operadores lógicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_Logicos)

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Como já disseram, o problema principal está no operador `||`. Mas você pode ainda usar uma função bem mais minimizada com [operadores ternários](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_tern%C3%A1ria):

```js
function centuryFromYear(year){
   return Math.floor(year/100) + ((year%100 ? 1 : year) % 10 ? 1 : 0);
}

console.log("Ano 85: séc. ", centuryFromYear(85));
console.log("Ano 101: séc. ", centuryFromYear(101));
console.log("Ano 1500: séc. ", centuryFromYear(1500));
console.log("Ano 1501: séc. ", centuryFromYear(1501));
console.log("Ano 1999: séc. ", centuryFromYear(1999));
console.log("Ano 2019: séc. ", centuryFromYear(2019));
console.log("Ano 2101: séc. ", centuryFromYear(2101));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do jeito que está sempre vai dar `1` porque logo na primeira linha (do `if`) verifica se é maior ou igual a `1` e qualquer numero passado sempre vai ser maior ou igual a `1`

sugiro uma função bem mais elegante:

```js
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    var newYear = year.toString().length;
    var stYear
    if (newYear >= 4){
        stYear = year.toString().substring(0, 2);
        if (year % 100 !== 0){ 
        return (parseInt(stYear)+1);
        } else {
        return parseInt(stYear);  
        };
    } else if (newYear >= 3){
        stYear = year.toString().substring(0,1);
        if (year % 100 !== 0){ 
        return (parseInt(stYear)+1);
        } else {
        return parseInt(stYear);  
        };
    } else if (newYear < 3){
        return 1;
    };
};

console.log(centuryFromYear(902));
```

[fonte](https://gist.github.com/dillansimmons/6e4b0cf88b99cc3a9149eebd1ded349a)